# Calling function in another file without declaration gives no compile error

Tags: c

```
//File a.c
void main()
{
    test();
}

//File b.c
#include<stdio.h>
void test()
{
    printf("Hi, I am test.");
}
```

I compile this code using "gcc a.c b.c". Then I run 'a.out' and output is "Hi I am test." My question is in a.c file there is no declaration of test() so why does the code compile?

Comment: are these connected ?

Comment: Did you see a warning? When I use `gcc` on your code I see a warning for an "implicit declaration of `test`".

Comment: Buy a C tutorial book. Then you will understand why. Do not switch the warnings off

Comment: Note that GCC 5.0 and later will complain because they default to C11 mode, whereas earlier versions default to C90 mode. (More accurately, it is `-std=gnu11` vs `-std=gnu90`.) Both C99 and C11 require a diagnostic, but the code may still compile unless you require `-Werror` to convert warnings into errors.

Answer (score 2):

The functions in C are `extern` by default, meaning the linker would be able to connect a function from file `a` to file `b` even if there are no `#include` or `extern` written by the programmer.

My gcc compiled it with this warning: `warning: implicit declaration of function...` meaning, by seeing `test();` the compiler guesses what `test` is, and continues on. If you would have defined `test` as `static` that would have failed, since `static` counters the default `extern`

One thing I think you should note is this `implicit declaration` also makes the compiler *guess* the return type of `test`, and it would think the type is `int`. That could cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles because that is required by the C standard (at least before 1999).  Support was dropped in the 1999 standard, although a number of compilers since still support it - albeit they can be configured to warn (e.g. about an implicit declaration) in such cases.

Specifically, for reasons of backward compatibility of C89/90 to pre-standard C, an attempt by code to call a function implicitly declares that function as returning `int`, and accepting a variable argument list.

This is what happens when the compiler is working through a.c

When linking, it will work, since the function has the same name.

This works in practice if the way the function is called (the usage of the return value, and number of types of arguments) matches the way the function is defined.     If there is not a match, the result is potentially undefined behaviour.  For example, if the function is defined with 4 arguments and uses all 4, but the caller provides 3, then the behaviour is undefined.   Similarly, if the function is defined to return `double`, but the caller assumes it returns `int`.

Practically, you are better off declaring all functions in all compilation units before they are called (eg. by including a header).  This allows the compiler some chance of checking if the way a function is called matches its declaration.

Note also that, in all C standards, `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.   Support of `main()` returning `void` is a compiler extension.